# A Little Brittle Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

## Riddle

I start with half of nothing, end with half of eternity

And in the middle lies a town, named "Monster Bakery"

## Little hint

> the word appears on this page, definitely.

Oh, and it isn't

> brittle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling the answer here is:

> **NUMBER** - a word which definitely appears on the page (as per the 'little hint') in the form of the OP's username: 'Number Basher'.

*I start with half of nothing,*

> [**NU**]LL means 'nothing'.

*end with half of eternity*

> EV[**ER**] means 'eternity'.

*And in the middle lies a town, named "Monster Bakery"*

> This clues '**MB**', the initials of the town, in the same way that 'New York' would be abbreviated to 'NY', or 'Los Angeles' to 'LA'.

The references to 'brittle'...

> ...appear to be a red herring, with little bearing on the puzzle itself. Though I am happy to be corrected on that if wrong.

Comment: EVERYTHING IS CORRECT!!! and Number is part of my username